# Roll 6-sided die x times, chance of 6 occurring 10 times given that 1 occurs 0 times.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I roll a 6-sided die an unknown number of times. The number 1 occurs no times, what is the chance that the number six occurs exactly 10 times?

I got as far as figuring out that I need the the probability that the die was rolled $x$ times given that a number occurred exactly $n$ times, however I can't figure out how to create an expression for this.

### Edit:

To make this absolutely clear, I will define the problem like this. We roll a die $x$ times, where $x$ is a uniformly distributed random number between $0$ and $n$, and count the number of times that each number appears, $n_1$ is the number of ones, $n_2$ is the number of twos, etc. We want to calculate the probability $P(n_1 = 0 | n_6 = 10)$. We can use the binomial theorem to find a value for $P(n_1 = 0 | x=y)$ and $P(n_6 = 0 | x=y)$ for any $y$. By adding these together for all $x$, it should be possible to to find that number. I believe that the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ exists, but I might be wrong.

Comment: This is equivalent to ignoring any rolls for which a 1 comes up, which effectively makes your die 5-sided.

Comment: The core of the question is that the number of rolls is unknown, but given that six occurred exactly 10 times, we can guess that the number of rolls is probably roughly 60. However, I need a more rigorous way of doing this to answer the question.

Comment: That’s not what you’ve written in your question, though. You ask for the probability of rolling 6 exactly 10 times, not for the probability distribution of the number of rolls needed to get ten sixes, which is rather different.

Comment: @InformationAether Your edit does not really clarify your question. Make it more specific. What is does $n_1$ or $x$ mean in this context?

Comment: what is given? $n_6=10$ or is it $n_1=0$?

Comment: $n_1...n_6$ are the number of times that a certain number appears. $x$ is the number of dice rolls, which is an unknown random variable. It is given that $n_6$ is equal to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- If a particular number $j$ occured exactly $n_j=n$ times out of $x$ times, then for the remaining $x-n$ times, the other number occur equally likely. We already know that for those tosses, the outcome can't be $j$, but for it take other values that is not equal to $j$,  it occur with probability $\frac15$ each.
- Let $X \sim Unif \{ 1, 6\}$, let $j, k \in \{ 1, \ldots, 6\}, j \ne k, $then we have

$$P(X=j|X \ne k)=\frac{P(X=j, X\ne k)}{P(X \ne k)}=\frac{P(X=j)}{1-P(X=k)}=\frac{\frac16}{\frac56}=\frac15$$

- Binomial distribution might be helpful for your question.

Comment: Sure, given that a certain number occurred n times, the average number of times that all other numbers occurred is n. But that doesn't mean a different number *can't* occur a different number of times. The greater the distance between between numbers, the lower the probability.

Comment: yes, they can occcur a different number of time, just saying that their distribution is now independently uniform, at a particular toss, each number happens with probability $\frac15$.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: hmmm... can you clarify what is your question?

Comment: "Given that a certain number offcured $n$ times, the average number of times that all numbers occured is $n$" doesn't make sense, it depends on how many tosses remain. For example if out of $6$ tosses, $1$ occur exactly $5$ times, then for the remaining one toss, the probability of getting $2$ is equal to $\frac15$, same for probability of getting $3$.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know the total number of tosses, but we have some idea of the probability of different numbers of tosses occurring. For example, if we roll a die 10000 times, it is very unlikely that 6 will come up as few as 10 times, and if the number of rolls is 10, it is unlikely that 6 will come up as many as 10 times. I believe that it is possible to assign a probability to each number of rolls.

Comment: My first comment was wrong, what I mean to say is that for large numbers of rolls, if the number of sixes is 10, then the number of 1s is statistically about 10, but it could be 0. I want to know what the probability of it being 0 is.